# Why Push function within a function is not adding value to an array outside the function

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

I made a array named "arr"
length of 3 value and I also added
addEventListener to 'formF' variable, when function of this addEventListener run it should 'push' *formArr* object to
to "arr" array which is outside the event function but it doesn't. But if  I console the 'arr' within the addEventListener function it shows that value is adding to arr array .And when I console it outside the addEventListener it doesn't add value to arr array. Could you solve this problem

I try spread operator and unshift function.

Comment: Logging it outside the event listener function means that log runs **before the function that mutates it has been called**!

Comment: You should provide more information regarding your question, and you might post your code to show people where you are stuck.